# VBA Access Textbox returning Null Value

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a VBA Access userform. In this useform there is a textbox with the name `txtSearch_POBOX`. I'm trying to get its value using the code below:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_FirstName_Change()
MsgBox ([Form_Client List].txtSearch_POBOX.Value)
End Sub
```

But this is constantly returning NULL. When even when there is a value inside the text box. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reference is wrong. It should read:

```
MsgBox Forms![Client List]!txtSearch_POBOX.Value
```

As it could be empty, you should use:

```
MsgBox Nz(Forms![Client List]!txtSearch_POBOX.Value)
```

Answer (score 0):

remember that if you want to intercept the text box value while digiting, until you "validate" the content change (e.g. losing focus) the .Value property is not updated.

For instance I used a text box to make a running filter of a submask: I wanted to filter the submask while digiting. 
To do this you need to use the .Text property.

In the following example I make a running filter of a list of Publishers:

```
Private Sub txtNameFilter_Change()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim strFilter As String

    If Not IsNull(Me.txtNameFilter.Text) Then
        strFilter = "Publisher LIKE '*" + Me.txtNameFilter.Text + "*'"
        Me.Filter = strFilter
        Me.FilterOn = True
        Me.txtNameFilter.SelStart = Len(Me.txtNameFilter.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Bye
Wiz